# Deploy WAR in CapeDwarf JBoss AS7

Tags: java, jboss, capedwarf

I tried to deploy my web application war file in CapeDwarf Jboss AS7 however I am getting this error:

**Updated:**

```
05:49:43,957 WARN  [org.jboss.as.capedwarf.deployment.CapedwarfLoggingParseProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) No such logging config file exists: WEB-INF/classes/logging-temp.properties
05:49:44,299 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."explorer.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."explorer.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "explorer.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.3.GA.jar:1.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.3.GA.jar:1.0.3.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011555: Failed to configure logging using 'logging.properties' configuration file.
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.configure(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:305) [jboss-as-logging-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentLogging(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:164) [jboss-as-logging-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:79) [jboss-as-logging-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120) [jboss-as-server-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ClassLoader instance is already registered to a log context (ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.explorer.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.ContextClassLoaderLogContextSelector.registerLogContext(ContextClassLoaderLogContextSelector.java:101) [jboss-logmanager-1.4.0.Beta1.jar:1.4.0.Beta1]
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.configure(LoggingDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:270) [jboss-as-logging-7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 8 more

05:49:44,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "explorer.war" (runtime-name : "explorer.war")
05:49:44,438 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."explorer.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."explorer.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "explorer.war"
```

This web application works fine using Maven

https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin

> mvn gae:run

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in our Beta2 release.

It's already fixed in upstream, and it will be in next Beta3.

As a temp workaround you can rename the logging.properties (e.g. logging-tmp.properties),
but make sure you also change the ref to it in appengine-web.xml sys properties.

Comment: You mean rename my web application logging.properties file? Like \WEB-INF\logging-tmp.properties? I did this but still getting error

Comment: Hmmmm, what about if you completely remove logging.properties file?

Comment: I'll cut a new release soon -- probably at the end of this week or early next week, which should have this fixed.